# Error when saving image

Tags: javascript, php, android, crc

I have problem when saving image.

The major problem is when I am saving the image on Android 4.1.2 (Samsung phone).

I got no problem when running on internet explorer or chrome.

(Also look at google for solutions, but found nothing that may help, i.e. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.graphics.png.devel/3612)

In javascript after I did some manipulations on image: rotate it, shrinking it by size I do:

```
mystr = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

the string is something like:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAJYCAYAAAC
>   ZpjcAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAABZ9JREFUeJzswQENAAAAwqD3T20PBxQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

when saving the image (sending it to php by 'POST' method). I got an exceptions:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png:  fatal libpng error: IHDR: CRC error in <b>*********</b> on line <b>105</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in <b>*********</b> on line <b>105</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatefrompng(): 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAJYCAYAAAC ZpjcAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAABZ9JREFUeJzswQENAAAAwqD3T20PBxQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA in <b>/home/********/saveImage.php</b> on line <b>105</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/*********************</b> on line <b>135</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/*********************</b> on line <b>136</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in <b>/home/*********************</b> on line <b>176</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/*********************</b> on line <b>183</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagerotate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/*********************</b> on line <b>211</b><br />
```

Sometimes, I got other errors, i.e:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>GET to /saveImage.php not supported.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

## I think the above error is related to the way I call ajax in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "saveImage.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        'scale': 1
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'ext': picExt,
        'src': s // ***** the main string for the image - about 300K ******
    },
    timeout: 30000
}).success(function (result) {
    // code doesn't reach here
    s = result;
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // code reach here
    if (textStatus === "timeout") {
        // ****** code doesn't reach here
    } else {
        // ******* code reach here
    }
    // ***** code reach here
});
```

I don't have "GET" method, but as I know that for javascript I did as following, there was also errors, but much less ...

```
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "saveImage.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
...
        xmlhttp.send("&scale=" + scaleRatio +
            "&top=0" +
            "&left=0" + 
// ...
            "&src=" + encodeURIComponent(s)); // **** src is the 300K string send to server.
```

and on server site I don't know if I shall decode the image 300K string, or not:

```
$imagebin = (urldecode)((string)$_POST['src']); // is decode necessary?
```

As I can guess, the way I call ajax is not correct (May it sometimes decode the string, and sometimes not?)

... and sometimes I got an error (I not got the same error again and again - it seems to be resolved randomly):

> HTTP 403

I got php version 5.4.21.
gd version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

What may be the problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As I investigated the case, there were two major problems that made the errors:

1. When using ajax by jquery $ajax, the string is not encoded by
   default, but may contains escape characters, especially when using
   $ajax with a very long decoded string, such as uri string of a
   picture.

So, I should encode the string on the client side, even I send the string with 'POST' method, i.e as following code (pay attention to the line with the asterisk and calling to function **encodeURIComponent(s)** ).

```
$.ajax({
    url : "saveImage.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        'scale': 1
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'ext': picExt,
        'src': encodeURIComponent(s) /*********/
    },
    timeout: 30000
}).success(function (result) {
    // code doesn't reach here
    s = result;
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // ******* code doesn't reach here any more ******
    if (textStatus === "timeout") {
        // ****** code doesn't reach here
    } else {
        // ******* code doesn't reach here any more ******
    }
    // ******* code doesn't reach here any more ******
});
```

That's why there were errors, such as:

> imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png:  fatal libpng error: IHDR: CRC error in ...

and

> GET to /saveImage.php not supported.

1. For the error 403 it was hosting problem.

First, some configurations can be done to have sub status codes, as explained on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Second, the error of 403.9 indicates that there were too many opened sessions,
so I have checked the location of the sessions by the php function: session_save_path(), and see lot of files start with sess_ - that files are sessions.

The sessions are expired for a well defined period of time, as session.gc_maxlifetime declared.

On my sites, sessions are expired after 1 hour and half.

So, the garbage collector should delete the sessions files - That didn't work well on my site, so I had lot of sessions files - That cause the 403 error.

What I did, is that I simply deleted the sessions files.

Problem solved.

Thanks :)